# Error when doing mulitple ProjectTo layers with EfCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to create an "design guide" for building rest apis in my company and i wanted to have a 3 layers structure with automapper, asp.net core and ef core.

```
Database Layer : DbSet Entities
Business Layer : Application Models
Api/Rest/External Layer : Dto Object
```

I've successfully manage to do that with the following gist : https://gist.github.com/Angelinsky7/49c86333584e3f9cece44a88e7febd4e

but as you can see i need to use a hack to make this work... (https://gist.github.com/Angelinsky7/49c86333584e3f9cece44a88e7febd4e#file-automapper_bug_lambda_projection-cs-L23-L24), (https://gist.github.com/Angelinsky7/49c86333584e3f9cece44a88e7febd4e#file-automapper_bug_lambda_projection-cs-L89) and (https://gist.github.com/Angelinsky7/49c86333584e3f9cece44a88e7febd4e#file-automapper_bug_lambda_projection-cs-L93)

```
public IEnumerable<SubLayer2> _Subs { get; set; } = new HashSet<SubLayer2>();
public ICollection<SubLayer2> Subs => (ICollection<SubLayer2>)_Subs;

cfg.CreateMap<Layer1, Layer2>()
  .ForMember(p => p._Subs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Subs));
cfg.CreateMap<Layer2, Layer3>()
  .ForMember(p => p.Subs, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src._Subs));
```

and i very don't like it (because even if this is working like that, in more complex senarii, it's not working anymore)

if i don't do the hack : https://gist.github.com/Angelinsky7/0e26507c07c066376d5a4de8726dd1f2

In the InMemory EfCore Case with Layer3 as IEnumerable: (i dind't have this one before creating the issue)
`Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'dtoSubLayer2' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync()`

In the SqlServer EfCore Case with Layer3 as IEnumerable: (what i would like to use)
`InvalidOperationException: When called from 'VisitLambda', rewriting a node of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression' must return a non-null value of the same type. Alternatively, override 'VisitLambda' and change it to not visit children of this type.`

In all EfCore with Layer3 as ICollection:
`Unhandled exception. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

What am I doing wrong ? is this totally not possible to do ? Is there a way for me to find NullReferenceException or VisitLambda that pop up the exception and customize this behavior ? It would be perfect to have this kind of solution because i would have exactly what i would like to build my rest api...

#### Source/destination types

```cs
internal class Layer1 {
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<SubLayer1> Subs { get; set; } = new HashSet<SubLayer1>();
}

internal class SubLayer1 {
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
  public Int64 LayerId { get; set; }
}

internal class Layer2 {
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
  public ICollection<SubLayer2> Subs { get; set; } = new HashSet<SubLayer2>();
}

internal class SubLayer2 {
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
}

internal class Layer3 {
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<SubLayer3> Subs { get; set; } = new HashSet<SubLayer3>();
}

internal class SubLayer3 {
  public Int64 Id { get; set; }
}
```

#### Mapping configuration

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<Layer1, Layer2>();
cfg.CreateMap<SubLayer1, SubLayer2>();

cfg.CreateMap<Layer2, Layer3>();
cfg.CreateMap<SubLayer2, SubLayer3>();
```

#### Version: x.y.z

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="9.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.0" />
```

#### Expected behavior

I should be able to use ProjectTo Multiple time to change layers without having to use a trick to do it. And i should be able to choose between ICollection and IEnumerable when i would like

#### Actual behavior

Depending on the implementation one the 3 exceptions rises (most of the time it's the 'VisitLambda' lambda one

#### Steps to reproduce

https://gist.github.com/Angelinsky7/0e26507c07c066376d5a4de8726dd1f2

thanks for all the help and thanks for taking the time !!!
(and sorry if this is a efcore issue but i was thinking : "because i can create a "hack" in automapper it's maybe here")

i came here because the automapper team decided that it wasn't a bug on their part (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3280)

Comment: You're using Automapper in a hackish way already. It's only meant to enforce some mapping conventions  - and that's all! In this case it's not even possible to see what is going on any more. Check [Automapper's Design Philosohpy](https://jimmybogard.com/automappers-design-philosophy/) by Automapper's creator

Comment: The very fact that your code is that complex, and *far* more complex than performing simple LINQ queries and then mapping DTOs as needed, should be a very strong indicator that something is wrong

Comment: it seems the issue come from the fact that i use IEnumerable and ICollection and transforming data from ICollection to IEnumerable  is the culprit.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i understand what you mean, but i don't feel that i dont respect Automapper philisophy but using 2 layers of DTOs.... in the end, my purpose is to a have simple LINQ queries (in fact if i don't use IEnumerable at all everything is working really smooth) but depending on "who" call the services i don't want to give the same possibilities...

Comment: That's not Automapper's job by any stretch. It's not meant to restrict the kinds of queries one can execute. That's not mapping

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, lbargaoanu claused the issue and then Jimmy Boggard came to help me understand why and how what i was doing was not a automapper issue

Comment: i don't want to restrict the kinds of queries by doing that, i want to map my model between layers entites -> models -> dtos and not simply entities -> dtos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that automapper cannot do what i would like to have.
My mistake.
Thanks for the community to help me.